# Naming steps as Tasks vs Statuses in Process Design

Tags: jira, workflow, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I am modelling a business process and trying to understand how systems would work together to enable the process. I have earlier used JIRA to implement a lot of processes by workflows. Over there we define a ticket, statuses and transitions to define the workflow functionalities.

Right now we are exploring BPMN to enable a business process. The constructs here include tokens and tasks. The systems (we use Camunda) that we use to implement such a process also include them as their primary building blocks.

I want to understand the philosophical differences in these approaches and what determines which one should I follow.

Comment: Stackoverflow is [not the place to discuss philosophical differences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Can you provide the models that you have already created so that you can show us, where you were stuck?

Answer (score 4):

BPMN was designed to describe a business process without all the technical details of a software system. As an result, a BPMN diagram can be used to talk about a business process with a technician as well as with management people. So, there is no fixed rule on how to use BPMN in detail for your process description.

In general, there a two ways how you can describe a process with BPMN.

**Task Orientated**

In this modeling style the `task` elements describe the activities which should be processed in a sequence. The activities can be something like '*create invoice*', '*complete order*', '*cancel order*', '*update database*'.... .
Gateways and Conditions can be used to route your 'token' through your process. Workflow engines with task orientated approach (e.g. [JBPM](http://www.jbpm.org/) or [Activiti](https://www.activiti.org/)) execute the tasks immediately from the start event until the end event of the process flow is reached.

**Event Orientated**

In an event orientated style the `task` elements describe the states of the process. The status can be something like '*in approval*', '*waiting for assignment*', '*accepted*', '*completed*',  ....
Event elements can be used to signal an event to change the status, like '*approve*', '*reject*', '*accept*'....
Workflow engines with an event orientated approach (e.g. [Imixs-Workflow](https://www.imixs.org)) are persisting the status of a process instance and react to external events.
An event orientated process design can be used to describe long running process flows.

So, if you want to express the **activities within your process**, then the task orientated approach is the right one.

If you want to express the **state of your process**, then the event orientated approach is the right one.

Comment: Be careful with your definitions : A `task` element in BPMN is a type of `activity`. `Activities` represent work that is performed within a business process, not states. Of course, a `task`with a label "In approval" tells me that someone is working on approving something but I would rather [use an intermediate event to represent states of a process instance](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/events/none-events/#intermediate-none-event-throwing). Or even better, if you are primarily interested in communicating a state, why not use a UML state diagramme ?